# Rails JQuery Mobile hash url resolve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

i have a rails 3.0.7 app with jquery mobile 1.0b1. 
jquery mobile links make smooth transitions to f.e. "localhost/#user"

when i make a direct request (or page refresh) to: "localhost:3000/#users" the server correctly gets a GET "/". 
after that i would expect a second GET to "/users" fired by jquery mobile, and a page transition to "#users" right? 
but all i get is a second GET "/" request.

Could anyone with rails/jquery mobile experience point me to the right direction.

Comment: Would look at: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/docs-navmodel.html rel=external

Comment: I still want to use the jquery mobile hash urls. I always thought that when i refresh the page with "www.myurl.com/#123" the first request is to "/" and jqm issues a second request to "/123" transforms this into ajax and transitions the page.